# HttpURLConnection with https InputStream Garbled

Tags: java, http, https, httpurlconnection, google-translate

I use HttpURLConnection to crawler https://translate.google.com/.

```
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 1082);
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
        url = new URL("https://translate.google.com/");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

        Map<String, List<String>> reqHeaders = conn.getHeaderFields();
        List<String> reqTypes = reqHeaders.get("Content-Type");
        for (String ss : reqTypes) {
            System.out.println(ss);
        }

        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        String s = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, 100));

        Map<String, List<String>> resHeader = conn.getHeaderFields();
        List<String> resTypes = resHeader.get("Content-Type");
        for (String ss : resTypes) {
            System.out.println(ss);
        }
```

Console is

[image]

But When I change url to http://translate.google.com/. 
It works well.

I know actually HttpURLConnection is HttpsURLConnection when i crawler https://translate.google.com/.
I try to use HttpsURLConnection and it still garbled.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");

The response is compressed, because the above line tells the server that the client is able to understand encodings specified in `Accept-Encoding`.

**Try to comment this line or handle this situation.**

There's a more specific implementation for *HTTPS* i.e. `HttpsURLConnection`, in case you're interested in https-specific features, e.g.:

```
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

....

URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: I'll try upadte Accept-Encoding.

Comment: @TomGrylls Try *removing* it. At present you are lying to the serve that you can handle gzip encoding when you can't. Or aren't.

Comment: I try my code without Accept-Encoding.It's return normal value although not correct value.And i will handle this. Thanks!

Comment: The best way to express your gratitude to the answerer is to accept the answer, given the fact it solves your problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I accept Jerry Chin's answer.Solves my problem.
My answer just recording how i resolve this problem.
If this approach is unreasonable.Let me know, I'll remove this answer.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
```

And then I check response Content-Encoding.It's gzip.

So i use GZIPInputStream to receive.

```
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
GZIPInputStream gzis=new GZIPInputStream(in);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzis);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

The InputStream is normal.

BTW,If you don't need Accept-Encoding,you can remove it.

And do not forget check user-agent. It's very important and different operating systems corresponding to different user-agent.